# EF4 Code-First causes InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, code-first, ef-code-first

I'm having an issue when trying to run my project each time it builds. It seems the initializer runs, but when it comes to the first query - it dies with the following `InvalidOperationException`.

```
This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a
connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has
been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply
an unopened connection.
```

For reference, I'm using the EF Code First CTP4, imported directly with NuGet. Connecting to a SQL Server 2008 R2

What I want to happen is to re-create the database if there are any model amendments and seed it with a few values for the lookup table. Both of these things seem to be supported* out of the box.

My setup is like so:

Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
    Database.SetInitializer<CoreDB>(new CoreDBInitialiser());
    // et al...
 }
```

CoreDB.cs

```
public class CoreDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}

public class CoreDBInitialiser : RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CoreDB>
{
    protected override void Seed(CoreDB context)
    {
        var settings = new List<Setting>
        {
            new Setting
            {
                SettingName = "ExampleSetting",
                SettingValue = "This is a sample setting value",
            }
        };

        settings.ForEach(d => context.Settings.Add(d));
    }
}
```

When it runs, it dies on a line similar to this, which is basically the first query it comes across after creating the database.

```
User data = (from u in _data.Users where u.Username == userName  select u).SingleOrDefault();
```

Things I don't think it is:

- **It's not permissions**: I've deleted the actual database itself within the SQL Server. The application recreates it around about the same time as that query is attempted to run (the initializer is set, then obviously it holds off creating until it's needed). I've also logged on to SQL Server as the user that is specified in my Web.config and they have full read/write access to the database. In fact, they probably should do as that account creates the databases also.
- **The database is being created**: Deleting the DB and it automatically recreates fine.
- **The connection string is correctly defined**, including the `providerName` attribute.

`<add name="CoreDB" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;User Id=TheUsername;Password=ThePassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

- It doesn't *appear* to be a bug in my code/logic, as once the query has failed successfully, **the code will start properly until the next time the application is rebuilt**. It's obviously could be, and likely I'd have to apply a work around in my code no matter what anyway. :)

**What to do?**

Ideally, I'd like to "not think about the database schema" much. I'd like it to be as it seemed to be in [Scott Gu's excellent blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx#7573964) (and follow up for [working with existing databases](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)) where things just worked out and disappeared away. For the most part this is true. It seems to be an issue with the connection not being closed at some point, but I can't find out how to rectify this issue.

A [few forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/adonetefx/thread/c5329e4b-0efb-4951-85b1-0a123579cc3d) / SO posts do imply the issue I'm having is basically because the initializers aren't working exactly as planned and the connection might be left open. The solution in other places appears to be to simply "don't create your own initializer", which isn't the greatest solution - but unless anyone has any ideas, I'll probably have to do until CTP5 maybe.

*yep, I know it's a CTP, so "supported" is probably not the word :)

Comment: Even i get the error , but on refresh i can connect to the database

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question title. I'm pretty sure EF4 does not cause anything by itself.

Comment: Just ran into this, but I was using the selection from VS2012 and there doesn't seem to be a place to enter extra options from connection string.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I know that it is to late for answer, but this post is high on Goolge and answer may be useful for someone. The problem is missing credentials. To prevent this you need to change your connection string to have:

```
Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True
```

Based on [this article](http://jayhollingum.blogspot.com/2011/03/ef-codefirst-databasesetinitializser.html)

Comment: I can't test this at the moment as I don't have CTP4 set up on my Dev machine anymore. But I'll give it the upvote and answer in hope that it's right for the googler's :)

Comment: Entity Framework 4.1 Update 1 contains a bug fix to remove the need to specify ‘Persist Security Info=True’ in the connection string when using SQL authentication.  
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26825

Comment: I was still getting this error with EF 4.1.x and have just updated to latest version (4.3.1) thanks to this answer and problem is fixed.

Comment: ...and I didn't need to persist security info.  (trusted connection is false by default in my settings)

Comment: I was using the visual studio User Interface called "Connection Properties" to connect to my database and had to click Advanced -> Then check both "Persist Security Info" and "TrustServerCertificate" as True, and it formatted the connection string as your described.

Comment: @BenAnderson Could you add that as a separate answer, based on using Connection Properties? I was in the same situation and your comment helped me more than this answer.

Answer (score 6):

As requested I am posting my comment as an answer.

My solution was very similar to bizon where the Trusted_Connection and Persist Security Info needed correction but I accomplished it through visual studio properties by going to:

**Server Explorer** -> **Modify Connection** -> **Advanced** -> Then check both **Persist Security Info** and **TrustServerCertificate** as True, and it formatted the connection string correctly

[image: screenshot of visual studio gui]

Comment: This is the correct answer when using any of the EF PowerTools or EF POCO add-ins.

Answer (score 5):

Just run into this problem while I follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620) under VS2012 and EF6. My solution is quite simple:

In the Connection Properties dialog which pops up when choosing "Reverse Engineer Code First", check "Save my password".

Problem solved, but I don't know the details about it...

Comment: this worked for me, i dont know why it fails. I already added the credentials in the connection string

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your connection string. It worked for me.

```
Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get this to work as I wanted. This answer is a bodge / opt-out, so be aware when making your decision on what to do.

I have reverted away from Code-First for the meanwhile until it's at a more stable version.
For anyone who is having this problem with the CTP4 as well, then you can get around it by losing your initializer and passing NULL into the `SetInitializer` method.

```
Database.SetInitializer<CoreDB>(null);
```

This of course means that you need to maintain your database each time you make a change, or change it for a single run and then change it back after it creates the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Never posted before, learning Entity Framework using MVC, using 2010 and a dev database server running SQL Server 2005 for the database. I'm mainly a windows app guy.

First part of tutorial went fine, it created the three tables thus far, then I encountered the error above after adding some more classes and the database strucure needed to change.

My fix was pretty brutal, I went onto the dev server and went into my login and I am a sysadmin on my own server, not surprising. So I went into usermapping and selected master and just ticked every box. It now works.

I don't know why this has worked or what the issue is, but hopefully someone who knows more than me can build on this 'bad fix' and make it better for others who have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong password. Strangely worded exception.