# This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database

Tags: entity-framework

I have suddenly started getting an error in my application.

The error is:

> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable
>   to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original
>   database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed
>   from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Nothing has changed in the code - and database access is fine throughout the rest of the code.

It stops on this line:

```
var filteredContacts = dc.EAContactLists.Where(o => teams.Contains(o.Team)).ToList();
```

I am lost on this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF4 Code-First causes InvalidOperationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324052/ef4-code-first-causes-invalidoperationexception)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try setting `Persist Security Info = True` in your connection string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!  For note - all I did was install the .net 4.5.1 framework on top of the 4.5.0.  Cheers, Mark

Comment: This answer, at least by itself, did not work for me.

Comment: Was having this problem when using Entity Framework Power Tools to reverse engineer a heavily locked-down database to Code First POCOs. Adding this to the connection string fixed the problem, many thanks.

Comment: This just started happening on Hosted VS2017 agent on Azure DevOps. Adding this to my connection string solved the issue. We create a local db on the fly for our integration tests.

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue and in my case resolved it by adding "Integrated Security=True" to the connection string. This only applies if you're connecting to the DB using Windows Authentication. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just arrived at this and realised I'd already upvoted it the last time I had this issue. You've helped me twice. If I could upvote you again I would.......

Comment: I forgot to add this, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 13):

This error happened to me and none of the above worked. Embarrassingly, I realised that I had missed out a semi-colon from the connection string. Might be useful...

Comment: Saved my time..maaaaaan :)

Comment: Happenned to me when I forgot PASSWORD in connection string.

Answer (score 9):

Add `Integrated Security=True` for windows authentication.This worked for me.

Comment: wish I had seen your answer 2 hours ago!

Answer (score 3):

Hello actually this problem persist if you are trying to make changes in the schema like creating the table or altering some object...

And you don't have privileges to do that..

If you are working with MVC and your database already exit in the server than this problem can be solved with the code

```
Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeContext>(null);
```

just add this code in the Global.asax file in the application_start Event method.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Adding "Integrated Security=True" as suggested in the accepted answer is a "hack" to be used in the development phase and should not be used in the production environment since the security-sensitive information like UserId and Password can be obtained from connection after it has been opened, therefore, it is a partial solution.

Comment: I`m trying to Seed data, without changes ot the scheme and still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on windows authentication :

- You can add "Integrated Security=True" to your connectionString.

For user authentication:

- You must add sql server authentication informations ("uid=YourUserName; Password=yourpassword;") to your connectionString.

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid. I faced the same error and then I realized that I was running the update-database -verbose command in Package Manager Console in Release mode when I hadn't configured the transformations for release mode.

Here is the connectionstring format that worked for me in Debug mode.

> Password=dumbeldore;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=johnmcclain;Initial Catalog=DB_diehard400;Data Source=killthatbill;

- sensitive info in the connectionstring edited for security reasons. Please follow only the format.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that my password contained an `&` sign.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you aren't running Fiddler. Temporarily disabling traffic capture with F12 resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Had this same issue. Found out that in my connection string, where it says `"Persist Security Info = True;"`, I was missing the semi-colon at the end. Added the semi-colon and everything worked

Answer (score -1):

I Used this config in my code:
**Integrated Security=true;**

as this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog = MyDatabase_DB; Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and it worked.

Comment: There are multiple answers telling this. Please only add an answer if you have something really new. If an answer is helpful you may want to vote for it instead of repeating it.