# How to set the name of ConnectString dynamically in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, connection-string

I have a connectionString as follows:

```
 <add name="EDentalCADBContext" connectionString="data source=*.*.*.*\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=*******;User id=*****;Password=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I created the same ConnectionString dynamically, but I am unable to set the name of the ConnectionString such as name="EDentalCADBContext" in above.

How can I set the name dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: You're not meant to. Your web.config file is meant to be read-only and not modified by the program that loads it. You still can, but I want to know why you want to, before proceeding further.

Comment: I dont want to use ConnectionString from web.config. I created it dynamically. So I need to set the name to match it with DBContext.

Comment: I have copied my code. context.Users .ToList() is throwing the error. It's looking for EDentalCADBContext name in connectionString. Should it be same?

Comment: @Rehaan, where are you getting the name of database to which u want to connect? Is it from a session?? when user logs in?

Comment: i have a dropdown contained with Database names from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dai above. If you are creating it dynamically in the code, then what's the point of putting into a configuration wrapper. Why not just use it directly? The point of that entire interface is really to read stuff out from the common .config files.

Nevertheless, it *is* possible to do. When you create a ConnectStringSettings instance, you pass 'name' and 'connectionString' in the constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd8h82yf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you tell me am I doing correct?

string providerString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
            ConnectionStringSettings css = new     ConnectionStringSettings("EDentalCADBContext", providerString);

            conn = new SqlConnection(css.ToString());

Comment: I wouldn't expect ToString() to necessarily return the connection string value. If it does, it's still not very clear. Use css.ConnectionString property instead. But still, this seems overly complicated. Why not just pass sqlBuilder.Connection string in to the connection? Ex: conn = new SqlConnection(sqlBuilder.ConnectionString);

Comment: ...and as an alternative, as the earlier posts pointed out, if eventually in the code you are getting to a DbContext object, this will work: DbContext myContext = new DbContext(sqlBuilder.ConnectionString);  --the MS reference states you can pass a connection string name -or- the actual literal connection string. Both work.

Comment: I have copied my code above. Could you tell me the best solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you wrote

> I dont want to use ConnectionString from web.config. I created it dynamically. So I need to set the name to match it with DBContext

The solution is not to match the "magic string" that the `DbContext` expects (I imagine this was specified when you used the EF wizard in Visual Studio) but instead use the `DbContext` constructor that accepts a raw connection string:

```
String connectionString = "server=dbserver.local;Integrated Security=SSPI;...";
using( DbContext db = new DbContext( connectionString ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but the MSDN docs are peculiar. The constructor overload that takes only string makes no mention of "connection string name or actual string" but this one does: DbContext Constructor (String, DbCompiledModel) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext. Do both support it and the docs are wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I read it wrong. Both overloads state it explicitly: *Constructs a new context instance using the given string as the name -OR- connection string for the database to which a connection will be made.* Everytime I read it, my brain tricks me into reading "name -OF- connection string"

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the same SQL error. If I uncomment ConnectionString in Web.Config then its OK. If I change the name of ConnectionString, gives the same error. The Error is:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: @Rehaan Please post the code that defines the default (parameterless) constructor for your `DbContext`. The error you're getting sounds like you're using the wrong `server=` value in your connection string.

Comment: It worked but another throwing error : [InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.]

Comment: @Rehaan That sounds like you have other problems going on. For a start, why are you using the `master` database? Are you using SSPI or credentials embedded in the connection string?

Comment: I have credentials in my connectionString

Answer (score 0):

```
 EDentalCADBContext context = new EDentalCADBContext();

  public ActionResult Masters(int? pageNumber, string tableName)
                {
                    EstablishConnection(); // This creates the connection with DB dynamically.


                    int? page = 1;
                    ViewData["MenuItems"] = MenuItem.ActivateMenu("Masters");
                    ViewData["Users"] = context.Users.ToList();
        }

     public class EDentalCADBContext : DbContext
        {
           // public EDentalCADBContext() : base("EDentalCADBContext") { }
            public DbSet<NotificationItem> NotificationItems { get; set; }
            public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

It is expecting EDentalCADBContext name of the connection string. Why should it match?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stabbing in the dark without knowing specifically how the rest of your code works. But you asked me to try, so here's my best go...

If you have your own custom class inheriting from DbContext then you have to implement your own constructor to take in the connection string. You don't get to inherit non-default constructors. So I've modified your class below to have a constructor to take in the string:

```
public class EDentalCADBContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<NotificationItem> NotificationItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public EDentalCADBContext(string connectionNameOrString) :
        base(connectionStringOrName) {
    }
}
```

You would instantiate like this:

```
EDentalCADBContext context = new EDentalCADBContext("literal conn string");
// Perhaps comes from sqlBuilder.ConnectionString per your comments?
```

Comment: It worked but another error:  [InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977141/this-operation-requires-a-connection-to-the-master-database

Comment: already did that. throws same error as before:
...But there is nothing wrong with the connectString coz if I use it in web.config it works fine. 
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 0):

```
public EDentalCADBContext(string con = null)
    : base(string.IsNullOrEmpty(con) ? "name=EDentalCADBContext" : con)
{



}
```

In your EDentalCADBContext context class.
Then when you instance this EDentalCADBContext you passing a Connection string as parameter.
Ex. EDentalCADBContext db = new EDentalCADBContext(Connection string);