# Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to make **Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL Database** work for our **Web API** according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure) Microsoft resource. However I have not been able to connect from our application to the Azure SQL.

I have the **Active Directory admin set on Azure**.

Then I created a group "dbusers" in Active Directory on Azure. The Active Directory admin is also assigned to this group.

I set it on the database with following command.

```
CREATE USER [dbusers] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Everything up to here successfully completes.

I updated the web.config in my application to following:

```
Data Source=[my azure db]; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=[my db name];
```

When I try to connect to the database from the Web API I get following exception:

> Exception message: This operation requires a connection to the
>   'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master'
>   database because the original database connection has been opened and
>   credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an
>   unopened connection., Exception stacktrace:    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act)

To which I found a [workaround using following line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32635760/1350742):

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
```

Which gets me to another good old known execption:

> Exception message: The underlying provider failed on Open., Exception
>   stacktrace:    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.d__8.MoveNext()

I am starting to get crazy about how to configure this.

I am not sure if my configuration on Azure is faulty or if there is something wrong with my connection string or if there is something completely different to this issue.

**EDIT:**

One of the requirements is:

> To use integrated Windows authentication, your domain’s Active
>   Directory must be federated with Azure Active Directory. Your client
>   application (or a service) connecting to the database must be running
>   on a domain-joined machine under a user’s domain credentials

We are using Azure Web App & Azure SQL. How do I find this information or is this even possible without running dedicated VMs?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running all under Active Directory Integrated,
did you try to use SSMS and connect to your database using the Windows credentials? Was the connection successful as a specific Windows user
The alternative is to use AAD user/password
Also based on your string
Data Source=[my azure db]; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=[my db name];
the data source represents a server name in a format myazureserver.database.windows.net
and the database
mydbname
In addition you have created the user "dbusers" in mydbname  - correct?

Comment: yes, the user "dbusers" is created in the db as a contained user, the server name is as you are mentioning it. I haven't tried connecting to it with ADI as I am not running my machine under that user account.